# error running npm-windows-upgrade command

Tags: npm

After I run this command:

```
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
```

I am getting this error:

---

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: npm-windows-upgrade@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USERS1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04-12T15_31_25_623Z-debug.log


Here is the log file
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\USER1\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'npm-windows-upgrade' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.9.3
4 verbose npm-session 4b47ac8f869b6388
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/moment.js/npm-windows-upgrade 119130ms attempt #3
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for npm-windows-upgrade@latest 404 Not Found: npm-windows-upgrade@latest
9 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found: npm-windows-upgrade@latest
9 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (C:\Users\USER1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\fetch.js:42:19)
9 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Users\USER1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\USER1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\USER1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\USER1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
9 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\USER1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
9 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (C:\Users\USER1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
9 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\USER1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
9 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\Users\USER1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
9 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)
9 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)
9 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5)
10 verbose cwd C:\WINDOWS\system32
11 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
12 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\USER1\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "npm-windows-upgrade"
13 verbose node v8.9.3
14 verbose npm  v5.6.0
15 error code E404
16 error 404 Not Found: npm-windows-upgrade@latest
17 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

What needs to be done?
Thanks-

Comment: set the npm registry setting from "https://registry.npmjs.org/moment.js/npm-windows-upgrade" to "https://registry.npmjs.org" and it worked